# How to send an image and other form data in controller in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

here is my ajax call i am uploading an image using ajax. i want to send a text box data with image file. How it will possible in this function? Here is my function and ajax call

```
 function updateSpeciality(id)
    {
     var name = $("#speciality").val();
     var form_data=new FormData();
     $.each($("#myfile")[0].files,function(i,file){
       form_data.append("image",file);
     });
     $.ajax({    
        url:"<?php echo base_url('Dashboard/saveSpeciality');?>",
        type:'POST',
        cache:false,
        async:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        data:form_data,
        success:function(data){
          alert("i am in success");
        },
        error:function(error){
          alert("i am fail");
        }
     });
    }
```

i want to send value of var name with file as well to my controller function. Because in controller function i am saving name and file path in db. ajax call is going perfect but how will i send name value in this data ?

Comment: Can add data/text same as you are adding file. form_data.append('text', text). Check by printing $_POST and $_FILES both variables in controller.

Comment: yes it is working and can get through $_POST... Thanks

Comment: Just a side note; You should stop using base_url where you should be using site_url.